# Compare group of columns from one sheet in Excel with another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 5 columns in sheet 1 of Excel and my sheet 2 contains 10 columns.

Now my problem statement is I need to find complete record from sheet 1(combination of 5 columns) whether it is present in sheet 2, if it is present I need to identify that particular record in sheet 2.

Please let me know how to achieve this in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: It's very difficult to help without examples of either data set.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are used to Excel's VBA.
Here is a code I use for similar purpose : It require the user to specify two ranges. Then it compare values from secondary range to primary range. If values are matched, the double will be highlighted.

```
Dim G
Dim h
Dim LIMIT_G As Single
Dim LIMIT_h As Single
Dim Buffer As String

Sub KillDouble()

Set G = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select First Range", Title:="First Range Select", Type:=8)
Set h = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Second Range", Title:="Second Range Select", Type:=8)


Application.Goto G

With Selection.Areas(Selection.Areas.Count)
LIMIT_G = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Row - .Cells(1).Row + 1
    For j = 1 To LIMIT_G
    Buffer = .Cells(j).Value

    Application.Goto h

    With Selection.Areas(Selection.Areas.Count)
        LIMIT_h = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Row - .Cells(1).Row + 1
        For i = 1 To LIMIT_h
            .Cells(i).Activate
                If ActiveCell.Value = Buffer Then
                ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Hopefully this will help you.